# Custom Text Column data type error

Tags: sql-server, casting, varchar

I want to create a custom column that has is a URL made up of custom text and a column from the sql table. I've done this before, but am now encountering an error and unsure how to solve it.

```
select *, 'www.google.com/' | oporid
from #sqltable
```

The error I receive is "Error converting data type varchar to bigint." I then make the following changes:

```
select *, cast('www.google.com/' | oporid as varchar) 
from #sqltable
```

However, I receive the exact same error even though I'm casting the custom column to varchar.

When I simply create a custom text column it works fine, but when I want to incorporate OpOrID to create the URL (www.google.com/OpOrID) the error occurs.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The more I look at this the more confusing it becomes. The | is a bitwise OR operator in t-sql. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 Maybe you are trying to do string concatenation? That uses the + symbol

Comment: Bitwise or is not compatible with string.  Even if you cast to binary is that what you mean to do?   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-or-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I am trying to create a custom column with an output that concatenates the custom text I wrote (www.google.com/) with data from my existing table (OpOrID) so the result is a column www.google.com/OpOrID

Comment: concat(val1,val2,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please tell me it is not this simple

```
select *, 'www.google.com/' + oporid as url2
from #sqltable
```

If not varchar then use concat or cast

Comment: I think that is what they want. Only issue might be that oporid could be a number so it would require a cast/convert. But truly I think it is this simple. :(

Comment: From context I highly suspect that is varchar

Comment: You may well be correct. Hard to say for sure as there is very little in the way of detail.

Comment: oporid is a int

Comment: @George Then use concat or cast it.  You did not find the answer acceptable?

Comment: I received the same error when trying @paparazzo answer